# Techniques to solve family of nonlinear 2nd order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have some problems solving differential equations of the following form

$$A y''(x) + B y'(x) + \frac{C}{D+y} = E$$

where $A,B,C,D,E$ are constants. Is there a general way to solve differential equations of this form? Or do we have to use Laplace transform or some other transforms?

I would appreciate it if someone can help me solve these for equations clearly.

Comment: Not really straightforward, depends on the exact values of all these. For example, the ODE : $$5y'' + yy' + \frac{2}{1+y} = 1$$doesn't have solutions in closed form.

Comment: I am so confused then what if b was also constant?

Comment: [Still no closed form solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3*y%27%27+%2B+2*y%27+%2B+2%2F(1%2By)+%3D+1)

Comment: Hmmm thank you, so do we have to approximate our answers for differential equations of this form?

Comment: I tried some random examples. But some random examples are definitely not infinite, so I can't say something in general for that. Seems like yes, though. What problem are you interested in  solving ?

Comment: @Rebellos for instance the differential equation i want to solve is:
$$(M-1000t)y^{''}+ky^{'}=T_0\sin \alpha t -\frac{M-1000t}{r-y}$$

Where the function of $y$ is in terms of $t.$ I would appreciate the help.